# Why does golang use parentheses for byte slice and brackets for string slice?

Tags: go, byte, slice

I've always wondered why in golang you create a slice of bytes using parentheses:

```golang
[]byte("foo")
```

While creating a slice of strings using bracket notation:

```golang
[]string{"foo", "bar"}
```

Are parentheses used just because the expression expects a single value (e.g. the string `"foo"`), and so the parentheses are used as a 'grouping' syntax?

> Note: the use of 'group' or 'grouping' to define this behaviour is very likely incorrect on my part, but I don't have a better word to use off the top of my head.

I presumed so because golang also use parentheses in a grouping sense for things like type asserting `i.(T)` and for pointer dereferencing `(*p).z`.

Comment: The parens are a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) `T(v)`, i.e. to convert a string to byte slice you do `[]byte("foo")`. The curly brackets are [composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). You can construct a byte slice using a composite literal as well `[]byte{'f','o','o'}`.

Comment: Yes, notice that while you're creating a byte slice `[]byte` you're not listing byte values after it but a single `string` value. A literal would look like this: `[]byte{1, 2, 3}` or `[]byte{'f', 'o', 'o'}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this wrong.

- `[]byte("any_string")` is actually type conversion from `string` type to `[]byte` (slice type for byte) and its return type is `[]byte`.
- `[]string{"string0", "string1", ...}` is actually a `slice` of `string`s "string0", "string1", ...

Comment: Oh! I see. Makes sense now. Thank you!